# Pleonasmo bilingüe

Tags: lingüística, bilingüismo, pleonasmo

Encuentro entre gracioso e interesante esto de los [pleonasmos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo).

Me pregunto si con tanto anglicismo existe algún pleonasmo bilingüe.

Las respuestas de ChatGPT no son muy convincentes: "Salsa sauce", "Sofa couch"...

#### Edit después de los comentarios

Un par de ejemplos que me vinieron a la cabeza después de realizar la pregunta/encuesta, y después de consultar en Google para corroborar que son frases utilizadas.

**Spray pulverizador**: donde *spray* significa *pulverizar*.

**Estallido pop**: donde *pop* significa *estallido*.

Comment: Seria una contradicción y error de traducción.

Comment: Do you mean something like _rio Guadalquivir_ where the same concept appears in two languages?

Comment: Exactly, although I know there are more graphic examples

Comment: I have no idea what you mean; Guadalquivir is not bilingual. We just keep the Spanish word.

Comment: @Lambie I was thinking of examples like the English River Avon which is just saying river river since Avon (well strictly speaking Afon) is the Welsh for river.

Comment: @mdewey  The River Avon is not a bilingual and Afon is Welsh. So...that is a translation into English or a translation into Welsh. Dunno which came first.

Comment: Y como, "ivr" o "ibr" es una antigua raíz para "río" y otros términos asociados con los ríos, *río Gualdalquivir* significaría *río río río*.

Answer (score 3):

Un simpático ejemplo: los ***short cortos***. No sé nada del tema, pero sospecho que también existen los "short largos", lo cual sería un oxímoron bilingüe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In Spanish "pleonasmos" are very common, however, I can't find any similar in English.

In Spanish people use to say:
"Subir arriba" (to go up upstairs)
"Bajar abajo" (to go down downstairs)

those are the most common ones. I can't find anything similar in english. The only similar one would be this, that we have also in spanish:
"La familia real se va de vacaciones" (The royal family goes on holidays).

Comment: The question is about _bilingual_ pleonasm but your examples are totally in Spanish.

Comment: Hombre, pues "La familia real se va de vacaciones" funciona tanto en inglés como en castellano.